# What's wrong with this if elif else code in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm making a simple Rock, Paper, Scissor game. As you can see in the code snippet, the program asks the user if they want to play best out of 3 or 5.

If the input is `'five', '5'` or `'cinco'` the function `best_out_of_five()` executes (which prints `'5555555'` to console for now).
Similarly, an input of `'three', '3',` or `'tres'` prints `'3333333'`

My problem is that whatever input is read, it just executes the `best_out_of_five()` function (even if the input is 'three'). I thought the if, elif and else would be the easiest part of my code since I have done it many times before, but I must be missing something that I just can't notice.

```
import time

    def best_out_of_three():
        print('333333333')

    def best_out_of_five():
        print('555555555')

    name = input("Hi, what's your name?\n")
    print('Alright %s, lets play a quick game of Rock, Paper,'
          'Scissors. Do you want to play best out of 3 or 5?' % name)
    game_type = input().lower()
    if game_type in ['five', '5', 'cinco']:
        best_out_of_five()
    elif game_type in ['three', '3', 'tres']:
        best_out_of_three()
    else:
        print("That is not a valid answer. Try again later.")
        time.sleep(5)
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common mistake.  What you need is

```
if game_type == "five" or game_type == '5' or game_type == 'cinco':
```

**or** operates on boolean expressions, and does not distribute across **==**.  To oversimplify the evaluation, I'll just say that most expressions evaluate as **True**; there are a few exceptions, such as **False, 0, None**.

In particular, '5' comes across as **True**.  When you say

if game_type == "five" or '5'

this *must* be **True**.

Answer (score 1):

Included this in edit, but your if check should check all options. One way to do that quickly is to use a list:

```
if game_type in ['five', '5', 'cinco']:
        best_out_of_five()
    elif game_type in ['three', '3', 'tres']:
        best_out_of_three()
```

If your input is in the list (a linear check against all values in the list), then it will return true.

Answer (score 0):

The conditionals are not correct. '5' is just a string and when used as a conditional it will evaluate as true while the string '' will be false. Therefore what you essentially have is

```
game_type == "five" or true or true:
```

This will always be true. Try

```
game_type == "five" or game_type == "5" or game_type == "cinco":
```